# JSON always starts with [null

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array that contains plenty of data. The format is always like that:

```
1:
UserName: "John Smith"
Priority: "2"
Time Occured: "02/09/2019 11:20:23"
Time Ended: "02/09/2019 11:20:23"
2:
UserName: "Tom Bill"
Priority: "4"
Time Occured: "01/08/2019 13:20:23"
Time Ended: "04/08/2019 15:20:23"
3:
UserName: "John Smith"
Priority: "2"
Time Occured: "06/08/2019 13:20:23"
Time Ended: "09/09/2019 15:20:23"
...
```

Then I am changing this one into json file but it always starts with:

```
[
null,
{
```

I am using JSON.stringify to make it work

```
result = JSON.stringify(array);
```

I have tried a few options, yet unfortunately it always ends with null at the beginning. Is there any way to remove the null from the beginning of the json, or maybe to replace it?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with a sample of your data?

Comment: I'm not getting null with your data..

Comment: seems like your array has no data in index zero.

Comment: [mcve] please - else we're all wasting our time.

Comment: To be honest I am not using anything more than this, Array example is exactly the same, also I am using only JSON.stringify, then I check it by console.log and I can see [null,{"UserName...

Comment: Oh right, that is true, there is no data in index 0 as I am deleting it

Comment: You can't have sparse arrays in JSON, so JSON.stringify puts `null` in empty slots: `console.log( JSON.stringify( Array( 5 ) ) );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to check *why* `null` is always the first item, but if you really can't change that, then you can use `.shift()` to remove the first element of the array before you stringify it:

```js
const array = [null, 1, 2, 3, 4]

// this removes the first element
array.shift()

JSON.stringify(array)
>>> "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

Comment: I was using delete, which was leaving a lot of mess, array.shift(), works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use this method to remove null, undefined, NaN, empty string from array use this code. This will filter the array. After filtering you can Stringify it:

```
Array=[null,1,2,3,null,4,undefined,7,NaN,"",8,]

// this removes the null,undefined,NaN,"" from this Array 

var filtered = Array.filter(function(el) { return el; });
JSON.stringify(filtered)

console.log(filtered)  //"[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]"
```